# Erro ao tentar instalar módulos no NodeJS: "Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT HON env variable."

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web

Quando tento instalar os módulos que necessito ele me retorna vários erros no momento da instalação (nesse caso tentei instalar o socket.io):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Ivan Silva>npm install socket.io
\
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_m
odules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\w
s\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\nodej
s\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\n
ode_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modul
es\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\w
s\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\nodejs\no
de_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" re
build )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\n
ode_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_m
odules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modul
es\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_mo
dules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not define
d npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\
node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-c
lient\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modul
es\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\b
ufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_mo
dules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined np
m_config_node_gyp (node "C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node
_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:114:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\confi
gure.js:69:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\
bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan Silva\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-c
lient\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
socket.io@1.3.7 node_modules\socket.io
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.4 (isarray@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, component-emitter@1.1.2,
 benchmark@1.0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.3.1 (object-keys@1.0.1, debug@1.0.2, socket.io-parser@2.
2.2)
├── engine.io@1.5.4 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.2.2, ws@0.8
.0)
└── socket.io-client@1.3.7 (to-array@0.1.3, indexof@0.0.1, debug@0.7.4, backo2@1
.0.2, object-component@0.0.3, component-emitter@1.1.2, component-bind@1.0.0, has
-binary@0.1.6, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.5.4)

C:\Users\Ivan Silva>
```

Comment: Veja as configurações de Proxy

Comment: Você poderia postar o restante do log? Apenas essa parte naõ ajuda muito a identificar o erro. Eu até tenho uma ideia de qual possa ser, mas preciso ter certeza do erro.

Comment: Vou fazer isso.

Comment: Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable

Comment: Desculpas, não sabia =)

Comment: Tá faltando Python na minha máquina é isso?

Comment: Relacionado: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629

Comment: **Opinião pessoal:** Quando preciso instalar pacotes com muitas dependências utilizo o [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), ele irá se encarregar de verificar e instalar as dependências.

Comment: Parece que é isso mesmo.

Comment: depois de instalar o install windows build tools, seta a versão no npm "npm config set msvs_version 2017" aqui me salvou. Outra opção é instalar o windwosbuildtool remover o python e instalar via scoop (scoop install python27)

Answer (score 26):

No Windows, você precisa instalar algumas ferramentas de build (Python incluído). Basta executar no PowerShell (como administrador) a seguinte linha:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: Essa deve ser a resposta aceita; simples, objetiva e funciona sem mais esforços. Dica: não se esqueça de executar o prompt de comandos no modo administrador

Answer (score 5):

O log da instalação mostra que você não tem o Python instalado, ou que ele pelo menos não pode ser encontrado por não estar na variável de ambiente PATH do seu Windows. Faça o seguinte, verifique se o Python está instalado na sua máquina, caso não estiver acesse o site oficial e baixe.

Outra coisa, o log não deixa claro qual versão do Python ele precisa para completar a instalação pode ser que seja a versão 2.x ou a 3.x, quando é a versão 3 geralmente fica escrito `python3` no log, mas não é uma regra. Nesse caso vale a pena tentar instalar o Python 2 primeiro.

O [página de download do Python é essa](https://www.python.org/downloads/), nela você encontrará as duas versões disponíveis.

Caso você já tenha o Python instalado, o erro provavelmente estaria ocorrendo porque o diretório de instalação dele não está na variável de ambiente PATH do seu sistema, para adiciona-lo basta seguir os passos abaixo:

- Aperte no teclado <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>;
- Na janela que abriu, clique na opção Configurações Avançadas de Sistema que pode ser localizada na lateral esquerda da janela;
- Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente;
- Concatene o diretório de instalação do Python à variável Path, no caso da versão 2.7 seria algo como `;C:\python27`, note que é necessário aquele `;` no início;
- Reinicie o Prompt de Comando.

Comment: Já fiz todo o procedimento. Agora como verifico se o socket.io foi instalado corretamente?

Comment: Sim, mas antes de verificar se consegue realizar a instalação, verifique se o Python está acessível pelo Prompt de Comando, abra o Prompt e digite `python --version`, o retorno deve ser a versão que está instalada. Já tive esse erro quando tentei instalar um pacote pelo `npm`, e imagino que depois você ainda terá outro relacionado a outra coisa, mas vamos ver. Qualquer coisa me atualize aqui nos comentários.

Answer (score -1):

Comigo funcionou da seguinte maneira.

Instalei a última versão do python:  https://www.python.org/downloads/

rodei:
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

abri um novo command 
npm install

espero que ajude.